# VS code Default terminal Profiles won't work on "Run Python in terminal" Button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I changed my terminal Default Profile to CMD and it worked just fine in the pasted but, from some moment it started to run in PowerShell when I try to run by "Run python in Terminal" button in the UI...

If I call terminal with shortcut ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> ) it works just as expected (CMD) but this just don't get to "Run Python in Terminal" (when i press the button this will start the script in PowerShell)

My default terminal profile was always in CMD and have no idea why it's suddenly not working...How to set my default Terminal always to be CMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people have encountered this question that It's a bug in v1.60.0 which will be fixed in next release.

See bug report: [Python extension does not honor default terminal type](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17015)